# Using bundler with statically linked ruby in OS X 10.9

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to OS X 10.9, I reinstalled ruby with `rvm reinstall 2.0.0`, installing rvm's statically linked ruby. Now when I run `bundle install` in a project, I get problems coming from bundler. I upgraded to bundle-1.5.0rc1 with no success.

```
$ bundle install
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/Users/nik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': undefined class/module Digest::Base (ArgumentError)
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:245:in `install'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  from /Users/nik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

The workaround is to use a dynamically linked ruby: `rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --disable-binary`

This Bundler bug is documented here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2715

Comment: You should put the workaround as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to use a dynamically linked ruby: `rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --disable-binary`

This Bundler bug is documented here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2715